# OData and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, wcf, web-services, ipad, odata

I am trying to develop an ipad app that would interact with SQL server.Simple. So, i used WCF web service.  I am getting the data there as xml. now, i want to develop an objective c client that would consume it. So, i used the odatagen tool to generate proxy. I did that and i got 2 files xyz.h and xyz.m. No more files. Now i have included them in my project. But in the xyz.h file i have error that says "import "OdataObject.h" file not found. I have done the header search path and library search path settings. What is missing.?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include in your project the files that you should have in the OData4ObjC repository you cloned from github (or codeplex):

- the .a library located in the /framework/bin/odatalib/lib/-yourplatform-/-yourversion-
- all the files located in the /framework/bin/odatalib/include folder